# What should be the size of images for the bootstrap responsive image columns?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to have 3 image only columns, lets say three `class="col-lg-4"` I'm aware of `class="img-responsive"`

How do I pick the size of the images I should use? How do I do the same if I have 4 `col-lg-3`

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I do in this case is use holder.js to measure the image widths for me: http://imsky.github.io/holder/

Then inside your columns insert fluid placeholders like this:

```
<img data-src="holder.js/100%x75/social">
```

When you load this in your browser it will tell you how wide each image needs to be.

** **UPDATE** (June 2016) **

here is the updated syntax:

```
<img data-src="holder.js/100px380" class="img-responsive">
```

Comment: You're right, here is the updated syntax (from https://github.com/imsky/holder/blob/master/README.md)

Important: Percentages are specified with the p character, not with the % character.

Specifying a dimension in percentages creates a fluid placeholder that responds to media queries.

<img data-src="holder.js/100px75">

Comment: To be able to get the full width I found out here https://github.com/imsky/holder/issues/190#issuecomment-228105124 `<img data-src="holder.js/100px380" class="img-responsive">`